# FullCalendar.. events.. where remove Event excludes more than one

Tags: angular, web, fullcalendar

I have a difficulty using fullcalendar.

When I will delete a record or edit. I get an event object.

And whenever I delete something it ends up excluding other events that it should not. on my console there is always more than 1 event.

Another example:
I click on an event.left this event and did no action with it. edit another event and end up excluding it. it deletes the previous event and the current event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#data').datepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true
  });

  $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    // navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
      $('#calendarModal').modal();
      $('.modal').find('#paciente').val('');
      $('.modal').find('#data').val(diaClick);
      $('.modal').find('#horaInicial').val(horaClick);
      // const title = prompt('Event Title:');
    //   let eventData;
    //   if ($('#paciente').val()) {
    //     eventData = {
    //       title: $('#paciente').val(),
    //       start: start,
    //       end: end
    //     };
    //     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    //   }
    //   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events,
    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {

      $('#opcoesModal').modal();

      $('#agendado').off('click', function() {
        event.color = '#B2DFEE';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

      $('#confirmado').off('click', function() {
        event.color = '#0000FF';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

      $('#aguardando').off('click', function() {
        event.color = '#00FF00';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

      $('#atendido').off('click', function() {
        event.color = '#43CD80';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

      $('#faltou').off('click', function() {
        event.color = 'red';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

      $('#desmarcou').off('click', function() {
        event.color = '#8B5A2B';
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

      $('#alterar').off('click', function() {
        editar = 'S';

        // start tras as informações ao editar agenda
        $('#paciente').val(event.title);
        $('#data').val(moment(event.start, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
        $('#horaInicial').val(moment(event.start, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm'));
        $('#horaFinal').val(moment(event.end, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm'));
        // end tras as informações ao editar agenda

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');

        $('#calendarModal').modal();

      });

      $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
        if (editar === 'S') {

          event.title = $('#paciente').val();
          const data = $('#data').val();
          const horaInicial = $('#horaInicial').val();
          const horaFinal = $('#horaFinal').val();

          event.start = moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + horaInicial;
          event.end = moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + horaFinal;

          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

          // hide modal
          $('.modal').modal('hide');

        }
      });

      $('#excluir').off('click', function() {
        console.log(event.id);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' , event.id );

        $('#opcoesModal').modal('hide');
      });

     },
    events: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-09-01',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-09-07',
        end: '2017-09-10',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-09-09T16:00:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-09-16T16:00:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2017-09-11',
        end: '2017-09-13',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-09-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2017-09-12T12:30:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2017-09-12T12:00:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-09-12T14:30:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2017-09-12T17:30:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2017-09-12T20:00:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2017-09-13T07:00:00',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2017-09-28',
        color: '#B2DFEE'
      }
    ],
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      // dia clicado
      diaClick = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      horaClick = moment(date).format('HH:mm');
    }
  });

  // Whenever the user clicks on the "save" button om the dialog
  $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
    if (editar === 'N') {

      console.log(editar);
      const title = $('#paciente').val();
      const data = $('#data').val();
      const horaInicial = $('#horaInicial').val();
      const horaFinal = $('#horaFinal').val();
      console.log(title);
      if (title) {
          const eventData = {
              title: title,
              start: moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + horaInicial,  // 2017-09-13T07:00:00
              end: moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T' + horaFinal,
              color: '#B2DFEE'
          };
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
      }
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

      // Clear modal inputs
      $('.modal').find('input').val('');

      // hide modal
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code snippets.

Comment: Gernot.. i add code

Comment: every time "eventClick" runs you add more and more event handlers to your other buttons, but you never remove them. So if you've previously edited something or deleted something, next time you click any of those buttons again it will re-run all the events you ever attached to them. I haven't had time to study the flow in detail but that seems a likely cause of problems. Start using .off() to remove previous events from your buttons before adding new ones.

Comment: What @ADyson said. Or, instead of repeatedly adding handlers in `eventClick`, add them once, outside of your Fullcalendar code.  AFAICT the only thing that really happens on `eventClick` is to open the modal - you don't need to define your handlers there.

Comment: @don't Panic do you have any example?

Comment: @ADyson please confirm for me.. would it be this way?

Comment: An example of what? Just take your event handlers out of `eventClick`, and put them outside your Fullcalendar code.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Unfortunately it's not quite that simple, because the handlers contain things like `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` which rely on the `event` being in the scope of the eventClick callback, so if we move all the handlers outside the fullCalendar code there'd need to be an extra mechanism to identify the right event etc. in the circumstances each time it's clicked. That's achievable of course (by a variety of potential designs), but simply running ".off" to remove each of the previous handlers before re-defining them is likely to be a quicker fix.

Comment: I see, thanks @ADyson, I missed that.  I still think repeatedly adding/removing event handlers is a bad solution.  I'd try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/fmvnrb05/ . Paul, please try it.  It is a much simplified version of your code, without a modal, but the same principle can be applied.  Click an event, then click the button.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I agree it's not ideal, was just suggesting a quick fix. Your fiddle works nicely, although I'd say using globals wasn't necessarily the ideal solution either, but it certainly removes the event handler problem.